# How to clear the console input buffer

Tags: c, winapi, console

I'm basically making my own console I/O, (so no cout, cin, etc) but sometimes when I read the input I don't read all the characters on the buffer, because I can select how much I want to read. But the next time I call `ReadConsoleA/W()` it doesn't wait for the user input because it reads what is left in the buffer. I tried `FlushConsoleInputBuffer()` but it didn't work. Here is basically what I have:

```c
#inlcude <windows.h>

// These globals are here just for the example
DWORD bytes;
HANDLE in;
HANDLE out;

void WrtConsole(const char* text, DWORD size)
{
    WriteConsoleW(out, text, size, &bytes, 0);
}

void ReaConsole(char* text, DWORD max_size)
{
    FlushConsoleInputBuffer(in);

    ReadConsoleA(in, text, max_size, &bytes, 0);
}

// Im using `int WINAPI mainCRTStartup()`, but it doesnt matter, Im just not using any iostream things.
int main()
{
    out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    in = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    char num1[4];
    char num2[4];
    
    WrtConsole(L"First number: ");
    ReaConsole(num1, 4);
    WrtConsole(L"Second number: ");
    ReaConsole(num2, 4);

    // ...
}
```

Now, for example, if the user types a 3-digit number, like 100, the `ReadConsole()` function will read the '1','0','0','\r' but will leave the '\n' in the input buffer causing the next call to `ReadConsole()` to effectively just skip it.

As I said, `FlushConsoleInputBuffer()` didn't work, so, how can I clear the input buffer of the console so the next call to `ReadConsole()` isn't "skiped"?

Comment: I would like to point out already that the weird naming is because Im brasilian so I had to translate it to english.

Comment: Regarding `FlushConsoleInputBuffer()` not working, the [FlushConsoleInputBuffer function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/flushconsoleinputbuffer) page states "If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror)". I suggest adding code to confirm whether or not it's working and, if it's failing, what the error code is.

Comment: If you wish to ignore input you will have to ignore input. The system cannot help you with that.

Comment: I think it's possible that you are asking for a sure way to *clear the console input buffer* but what you may really **need* * is a better way to get console input characters -- like maybe one that uses API [ReadFile()](https://ideone.com/fork/peDaOZ) instead.

Comment: @IInspectable Im not ingnoring input, I want to clear the input buffer cause the user can type how much they want, but I can only get a x amount of these characters.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I just tried, the return of FlushConsoleInputBuffer is 1 (non zero) and GetLastError returns 0.

Comment: @gregspears can you tell me how ReadFile would be better? There is no argument that clears the buffer, it onlys removes the bytes that got read like ReadConsoleA/W.

Comment: *"Im not ingnoring input"* - Exactly. That's the bug.

Comment: @IInspectable How is that a bug? Its doing as intended, the only function that is not working is `FlushConsoleInputBuffer()`.

Comment: I'd try and tell you, but then you avoided posting the *actual* code (and compiler/linker options) you are using, so no one can test.

Comment: Seems that when input console is in line mode (the default), once a newline is read the line is put in a buffer separate from input buffer and FlushConsoleInputBuffer() has no effect. You either need to disable line mode or just read the entire line. See [ancient post](https://narkive.com/wYDzYFWO.6) about it.

Comment: You can try using `scanf("%*c")` to clear the  "\n". Or `getchar()`.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT `scanf()`and `getchar()` are not windows default functions, they are implemented on top of these functions, the ones Im using. +, what Im doing is a chalenge in writting my own io from scratch and using these would ruin the porpuse.

Comment: @EnderMega Have I reproduced it correctly?https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxc9F.png It seems to skip the second mumber to third one, right?

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT Yes, thats what happens, this happens because when the user press enter it also sends "\r\n". So what happened, in your case, is that the third number you typed when it gets sent to the console buffer it goes like "100\r\n", so its 5 characters, but "third number" ReadConsoleA reads 4 of them and the last one gets read by "fourth number".

Comment: Same case for the first to the sencond.

Comment: @EnderMega Please accept it If this is the answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

I figure out!

The problem is `ReadConsole`. `ReadConsole` reads character input from the console input buffer and removes it from the buffer.

However, `max_size` you set does not mean MAX size! Actually it is set by you to 4: `ReaConsole(num1, 4)`. `ReadConsole` does not read all character input.

When I set to 16, It can work normally.
[image]

**EDIT:**
Using the loop in `ReaConsole()` to the check the ending without '\n' and '\r' can it.

```
wchar_t c;
    DWORD u;
    do {

        ReadConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &c, 1, &u, NULL);
    } 
    while (u && c != L' ' && c != L'\n' && c != L'\r');
```

[image]

Comment: *"it defaults to 0"* - That's entirely made up. Besides, exchanging one arbitrary limit for another arbitrary limit does not solve the problem if the problem is the arbitrary limit.

Comment: @IInspectable My mistake. It is set by op to 4:  `ReaConsole(num1, 4);` So `ReadConsole` does not read all character input. I've already modify it.

Comment: Awesome. And now someone types 15 characters, and your "solution" starts failing in the same way as the code it was intended to fix.

Comment: The problem is that if you just pass 16 or any other bigger number 2 problems arise:
1 the user can still type more them what you place as max and there will still be characters left in the buffer.
And 2, what if my array cant handle more them 4? Thats why I used 4 as argument, thats the maximun my array can handle.
(If you tell me to use a bigger array, that doesnt fix the problem and this goes back to point 1, the user can still type more characters.)  
Still, thks for trying to help.

Comment: @EnderMega I've already modified my answer. Please check it.

Comment: The `sizeof` operator calculates the size in bytes of its argument. This is a compile-time calculation. The size of the string literal `"First number: "` is unrelated to the number of bytes in the console input buffer during program execution.

Comment: @IInspectable I've realized and already done. Just did not edit it in time.

Comment: Yeah, I also tought of just cleaning the buffer myself 1 by 1, the problem is that this is clearly super ineficient and its more of a work around. I still cant believe that there is no API that you call a function and it clears that buffer, cause, for example, does STD also clean the buffer 1 by 1? In scanf_s you can specify the max to read, but what about what is left in there?

Comment: @EnderMega An explaination can be found: ReadConsole reads all available characters from the console input buffer and stores them in a separate buffer that is not affected by FlushConsoleInputBuffer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684281/x86-masm-assembly-input-buffer-holds-old-input-despite-flushconsoleinputbuffer

Comment: That answers one question at least. Now, there is really no way to clean the rest of the buffer? For example, how does the STL library handles input? Isnt it possible to expecify the max amount of data you can receive?

Comment: @EnderMega Didn't you say just want to use windows default function???

Comment: @EnderMega Nothing new about it. C++ just use `getchar()` loop or `scanf(“%*[^\n]”)`.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT `getchar()` and `scanf()` are implemented on top of Windows or Linux functions.